# Convert If statement to switch

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, switch-statement

I tried to convert this code below to a switch statement but my skills are not perfect in c#. Could someone help me with this case, please?

```
protected void logobtn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("Location");

    if (cookie["Location"] == null || 
        cookie["Location"].ToString() == null || 
        cookie["Location"].ToString() == "" || 
        cookie["Location"].ToString() == "-- Europe and Eastern Europe --" ||
        cookie["Location"].ToString() == "-- Asia & South-East Asia --" || 
        cookie["Location"].ToString() == "-- North & South of America --"
    ) {
        Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
    } else {
        Response.Redirect(string.Format("Berava.aspx?Country={0}", cookie.Value));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it need to be a case statement? Looks ok as is, a case may make it more verbose than it needs to be since you are doing the same action for many of the options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this if you are using C# 6

```
switch (cookie["Location"]?.ToString()) {
    case null:
    case "":
    case "-- Europe and Eastern Europe --":
    case "-- Asia & South-East Asia --":
    case "-- North & South of America --":
        Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
        break;
    default:
        Response.Redirect(string.Format("Berava.aspx?Country={0}", cookie.Value));
        break;
}
```

The `?.ToString()` thingy returns `null` when `cookie["Location"]` is `null`. So that handles these two conditions:

```
cookie["Location"] == null || 
cookie["Location"].ToString() == null
```

And the others are pretty straightforward. I think you can understand.

IMO, the switch doesn't look as good as the original if. The if is probably easier to understand in this case. But if you *really* like the switch, that's fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

You may try below code:

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("Location");

            if (cookie["Location"]==null)
                Response.Redirect(string.Format("Berava.aspx?Country={0}", cookie.Value));
else
            switch (cookie["Location"].ToString())
            {
                case null:
                case "":
                case "-- Europe and Eastern Europe --":
                case "-- Asia & South-East Asia --":
                case "-- North & South of America --":    
                    Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
                    break;
                default:
                    Response.Redirect(string.Format("Berava.aspx?Country={0}", cookie.Value));
                    break;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("Location");

        switch (cookie["Location"])
        {
            case null :
            case "":
            case "--Europe and Eastern Europe--" :
            case "-- Asia & South-East Asia --":
            case "-- North & South of America --":
                Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
                break;
            default:
                Response.Redirect(string.Format("Berava.aspx?Country={0}", cookie.Value));
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to modify your condition to switch, If you really want you can use code below.

```
 string coo = Convert.ToString(Request.Cookies["Location"]==null?null:Request.Cookies["Location"].Value);
                switch(coo)
                {
                    case null:
                        Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
                    case "":
                        Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
                    case "-- North & South of America --":
                         Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
                    case "-- Asia & South-East Asia --":
                         Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
                    case "-- Europe and Eastern Europe --":
                         Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
                    default:
                        Response.Redirect(string.Format("Berava.aspx?Country={0}", coo)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("Location")?["Location"];

        switch (cookie)
        {
            case null:
                Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
                // DO STUFF
                break;
            case "":
                // DO STUFF
                break;
            case "-- Europe and Eastern Europe --":
                // DO STUFF
                break;
            case "-- Asia & South-East Asia --":
                // DO STUFF
                break;
            case "-- North & South of America --":
                // DO STUFF
                break;
            default:
                Response.Redirect(string.Format("Berava.aspx?Country={0}", cookie.Value));
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you definitely want a case statement then this should work:

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("Location");

if (cookie != null)
{
    string cookieString = cookie["Location"].ToString();

    switch (cookieString)
    {
        case "":
        case "-- Europe and Eastern Europe --":
        case "-- Asia & South-East Asia --":
        case "-- North & South of America --":
            Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
            break;
        default:
            Response.Redirect(string.Format("Berava.aspx?Country={0}", cookie.Value));
            break;
    }
}
else
{
    //this is the null case...
    Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Why do people down vote for an answer that works without explaining why they have down voted?